# groupby consecutive identical values in pandas dataframe and cumulative count of the number of occurences

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, shift

I have a problem where I would like to count the number of times the current value has not changed in a dataframe over rolling periods.

For example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':list('aaaabbab')})
```

would somehow give output of

```
0
1
2
3
0
1
0
0
```

I have been trying something along the following

```py
df['col'] = df['col'] == df['col'].shift(1)
df.rolling(window=3).sum().reset_index(drop=True, level=0)
```

I have added in the rolling as I will want to look at the full data set in terms of rolling periods but even without having it over rolling periods I can not quite figure out the logic.

I am not sure if I am missing something simple or this may not be possible using shift

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to generate a grouper for the change in values. For this compare each value with the previous one and apply a `cumsum`. This gives you groups in the `itertools.groupby` style ([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]), finally group and apply a `cumcount`.

```py
df['count'] = (df.groupby(df['col'].ne(df['col'].shift()).cumsum())
                 .cumcount()
              )
```

output:

```
  col  count
0   a      0
1   a      1
2   a      2
3   a      3
4   b      0
5   b      1
6   a      0
7   b      0
```

#### edit: for fun here is a solution using itertools (much faster):

```py
from itertools import groupby, chain
df['count'] = list(chain(*(list(range(len(list(g)))) 
                           for _,g in  groupby(df['col']))))
```

*NB. this runs much faster (88 µs vs 707 µs on the provided example)*

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so just to add some more to @mozway answer.

My goal was to count consecutives value for an entire huge dataframe effectively.

The pb I encounter is that by construction

```
np.nan == np.nan
```

will return **False** so you could have a whole column full of only NaN and yet the counter will be at 0.

A simple workaround would be to replace all NaN in your df by a value not already in it.
For instance in the case of a float dataset you could do

```
df.fillna('NA')
```

which will work but by changing the dtype of your columns to Object the following code will be much slower (20x on my set up).

I would rather advised something like :

```
all_values = list(np.unique(np.array(df)))
all_values = [a for a in all_values if a==a]
unik_val = min(all_values)-1
temp = df.fillna(unik_val).copy()
 
from itertools import groupby, chain
for col in temp.columns:
    temp[col] = list(chain(*(list(range(len(list(g)))) 
                               for _,g in  groupby(temp[col]))))
count_df
```