# groupby and then count identical consecutive values in pandas

Tags: pandas

I would like to count the number of times the current value has not changed in a dataframe over rolling periods. That should be done while at same time groupby on a third column.

Example

```
Input columns: 'group', 'col', output column: 'count'
```

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'group':list('ABABABABABABABAB'), 'col':list('aaaaaaaabbbbaabb'), 'count':list('0011223300110000')})
```

I need below solution extended with groupby on a third column ('group' in example above).
[groupby consecutive identical values in pandas dataframe and cumulative count of the number of occurences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69104005/groupby-consecutive-identical-values-in-pandas-dataframe-and-cumulative-count-of)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':list('ABABABABABABABAB'), 'col':list('aaaaaaaabbbbaabb')})

df['count'] = (df.groupby(df['col'].ne(df['col'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() )

df['count_wanted'] = list('0011223300110000')
```

Counting shall be done separately for each of the values in column "group".

Comment: how exactly is the counting logic then with an additional column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using a "helper" column to group by based on the change in 'col' from row to row:

```
colgrp = (df['col'] != df['col'].shift()).cumsum()
df['col_gotten'] = df.groupby([colgrp, 'group']).cumcount()
df
```

Output:

```
   group col  count count_wanted  col_gotten
0      A   a      0            0           0
1      B   a      1            0           0
2      A   a      2            1           1
3      B   a      3            1           1
4      A   a      4            2           2
5      B   a      5            2           2
6      A   a      6            3           3
7      B   a      7            3           3
8      A   b      0            0           0
9      B   b      1            0           0
10     A   b      2            1           1
11     B   b      3            1           1
12     A   a      0            0           0
13     B   a      1            0           0
14     A   b      0            0           0
15     B   b      1            0           0
```