# Count consecutive identical values in pandas dataframe and compute cumulative sum of occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = 

sample_type    data_window
   A                1           
   A                1           
   A                1           
   B                1           
   B                1           
   B                8
   B                1           
   C                2           
   C                1   
   C                1
```

I'm trying to count the maximum consecutive identical values =1 in `data_window` for each `sample_type`.

I'd like an output DataFrame like below:

```
df = 

sample_type    cum_count    
   A                3                     
   B                2            
   C                2
```

I've tried an approach similar to this: [groupby consecutive identical values in pandas dataframe and cumulative count of the number of occurences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69104005/groupby-consecutive-identical-values-in-pandas-dataframe-and-cumulative-count-of), using `groupby` and `cumsum`, but can't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Performance is not important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby_agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with a custom function:

```
max_consecutive_zeroes = lambda x: x.loc[x.eq(1)].groupby(x.ne(1).cumsum()).size().max()
out = df.groupby('sample_type', as_index=False)['data_window'].agg(max_consecutive_zeroes)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  sample_type  data_window
0           A            3
1           B            2
2           C            2
```

Example.

Suppose the following series (only one group, so don't need the initial `groupby_agg` here):

```
>>> x
0    1  # First group (2)
1    1  #
2    6
3    1  # Second group (1)
4    7
5    9
6    1  # Third group (3, the longest)
7    1  #
8    1  #
9    3
dtype: int64
```

Step by step:

```
# Remove other rows where values are not 1
>>> out = x.loc[x.eq(1)]
0    1
1    1
3    1
6    1
7    1
8    1
dtype: int64

# Create virtual groups based on values are not 1
>>> out = out.groupby(x.ne(1).cumsum())
[(0,  # First group
  0    1
  1    1
  dtype: int64),
 (1,  # Second group
  3    1
  dtype: int64),
 (3,  # Third group
  6    1
  7    1
  8    1
  dtype: int64)]

# Get the size and keep the max
>>> out.size().max()
3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(g):
    s = g['data_window']
    count, maxcount = 0, 0
    for e in s:
        if e == 1:
            count += 1
        else:
            maxcount = max(count, maxcount)
            count = 0
    return max(count, maxcount)

print(df.groupby('sample_type').apply(f))
```

prints

```
sample_type
A    3
B    2
C    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Edited to account for only consecutive 1's and not all values:

```
(df['data_window'].eq(1)
 .groupby(df['sample_type'])
 .agg(lambda x: x.cumsum().sub(x.cumsum().where(~x).ffill().fillna(0)).max())
 .reset_index())
```

or:

```
g = df.groupby('sample_type')['data_window'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().ne(0).cumsum())

(df.loc[df['data_window'].eq(1)]
 .groupby(['sample_type',g]).count()
 .groupby(level=0).max()
 .reindex(df['sample_type'].unique(),fill_value=0)
 .reset_index())
```

Original Answer:

```
g = df.groupby('sample_type')['data_window'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().ne(0).cumsum())
df.groupby(['sample_type',g]).count().groupby(level=0).max().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  sample_type  data_window
0           A            3
1           B            2
2           C            2
```

Comment: Using `diff` might be a good idea but that doesn't take into account if the values are 1. The diff of [8, 8, 8, 8] will be [NaN, 0, 0, 0].

Comment: good point, thank you, I modified my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
out = (df['data_window'].ne(1).cumsum()[df['data_window'].eq(1)]
         .groupby(df['sample_type'])
         .agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().iat[0])
         .reset_index(name='cum_count'))
print (out)
  sample_type  cum_count
0           A          3
1           B          2
2           C          2
```

**How it working**:

First is create consecutive groups by values in `data_window` column by compare values for not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and create consecutive groups by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
#helper column g for better see groups
print (df.assign(g = df['data_window'].ne(1).cumsum()))
  sample_type  data_window  g
0           A            1  0
1           A            1  0
2           A            1  0
3           B            1  0
4           B            1  0
5           B            8  1
6           B            1  1
7           C            2  2
8           C            1  2
9           C            1  2
```

Then filter groups by `1` in `data_window` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df['data_window'].ne(1).cumsum()[df['data_window'].eq(1)])
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
6    1
8    2
9    2
Name: data_window, dtype: int32
```

So possible count these values per `sample_type` by lambda function with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and because top county value is first select first value by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
print (df['data_window'].ne(1).cumsum()[df['data_window'].eq(1)]
         .groupby(df['sample_type'])
         .agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().iat[0]))

sample_type
A    3
B    2
C    2
Name: data_window, dtype: int64
```

Performance depends of number of groups, number of consecutive groups and number of rows, best test in real data.

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000


df = (pd.DataFrame({'sample_type':np.random.randint(1000, size=N).astype(str),
                   'data_window': np.random.choice([0,1,2], size=N)})
       .sort_values('sample_type', ignore_index=True)
       .assign(sample_type = lambda x: 'group_' + x['sample_type']))
#print (df.head())
```

---

```
In [41]: %%timeit
    ...: (df['data_window'].ne(1).cumsum()[df['data_window'].eq(1)]
    ...:          .groupby(df['sample_type'])
    ...:          .agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().iat[0])
    ...:          .reset_index(name='cum_count'))
    ...:          
351 ms ± 1.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

```
In [42]: %%timeit
    ...: def f(g):
    ...:     s = g['data_window']
    ...:     count, maxcount = 0, 0
    ...:     for e in s:
    ...:         if e == 1:
    ...:             count += 1
    ...:         else:
    ...:             maxcount = max(count, maxcount)
    ...:             count = 0
    ...:     return max(count, maxcount)
    ...: 
    ...: (df.groupby('sample_type').apply(f))
    ...: 
    ...: 
393 ms ± 1.44 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#Corralien solution - `groupby.agg` is called another `groupby`, so performance is slowiest.
In [43]: %%timeit
    ...: max_consecutive_zeroes = lambda x: x.loc[x.eq(1)].groupby(x.ne(1).cumsum()).size().max()
    ...: out = df.groupby('sample_type', as_index=False)['data_window'].agg(max_consecutive_zeroes)
    ...: 
    ...: 
1.01 s ± 21.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```